# How to generate all trees having n-nodes and m-level depth? The branching factor is variable and need not be constant within the tree itself

Tags: algorithm, tree

Quite straightforward question I believe.^

For example a 5 node 3 level algorithm would eliminate

```
 A
 |
 B
 |
 C
 |
 D
 |
 E
```

but not

```
    A
   /|\
  B C D
       \
        E
```

which is the same as (atleast to me)

```
    A
   /|\
  D C B
 /
E
```

For example a 3-Node 2-Level algorithm would generate the following only:

```
   (1)               (2)             (3)

    A                 B               C
   / \        or     / \       or    / \ 
  B   C             A   C           A   B
```

Notice that I consider the tree below to be the same as (2) above:

```
       B
      / \
     C   A
```

Comment: You want to generate them all, not just count them? A simple recursion should work fine.

Comment: However, you need to be more precise. Are the children *ordered*? In other words, would the tree `(A (D E) B C)` be different from your second example?

Comment: @rici Want to just generate them all. No need for specific ordering. I need to iterate through all structures and determine a very small sample set from them that satisfies some set of conditions based on a pre-defined function. Also the order does not matter as long as the connections(links) are preserved.

Comment: Basically , I want to identify the structure that given the set of n-numbers , preserves the property that the children of any node add up to that parent. Like B+C+D = A as above. However, since I am working with energy data , I need to account for some tolerance in this addition. Would expect B+C+D in the range [0.7A....A....1.3A] i.e 30 % tolerance for instance.

Comment: I'm not asking about the order of generation. I'm asking about the ordering of children nodes in the tree. With your comment, I'm now even less clear what you're looking for. Are the labels important? I think you could make it clear by adding to your question a *complete* set of trees with four nodes and two levels.

Comment: My approach was to generate all these structures, replace A,B,C,D,E with their corresponding values and identify the best set of structures that try to above the above property

Comment: Order of generation is irrelevant.

Comment: Have edited my question description to indicate that structures are the same if the links they follow are the same.

Comment: Um. But you're saying that's different from `(A (D C) B E)`, right? In other words, the labels are important but the order of children is not. Sorry to be so pushy about precision, but all of these options are applicable to *some* question about generating trees, and your particular use case is not obviously the canonical one. As above, I'd suggest including a *complete* output of the expected generation for a small case. Even three nodes and two levels would probably do.

Comment: Am not sure how to interpret   `(A (D C) B E)`   as a tree structure. However , I shall add a complete example for a smaller case to my question.

Comment: It's an S-expression. In every parenthesized list, the first element is the label of the parent node, and the remaining elements are child nodes. Leaf nodes are represented without parentheses.

Comment: Ah. Makes sense. In that case , my second example is  `(A B C (D E))`  which is (for me) the same as  `(A (D E) B C)`   or  `(A (D E) C B)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic structure of the solution will be recursive, although the precise details vary depending on the precise equivalence classes you are assuming for the generation. Here you'll need to consider questions such as whether the nodes are labelled or not, and whether the children of a node are ordered or not. Each of these choices defines a very different but equally interesting generation problem.

The essential algorithm is to figure out an enumeration of possible sets of children, obeying the equivalence classes defined for the particular problem by producing only a canonical entry for each equivalence class. For unlabelled trees with ordered children, for example, we might start by enumerating all the ordered partitions of the node count; for a given partition, we would form the Cartesian product of all the different possible subtrees of the indicated sizes. If we dodn't care about the order of the children, we'd need to find some way of making canonical lists of children: we could first sort the subtrees by total size, but then we'd need a canonical order for two subtrees of the same size. This gets tricky, but there are solutions.

I gather that your problem does not just have a number of nodes but rather specific node labels, and therefore two trees with the same shape but different labellings are to be considered distinct. However, you want the order of children to be irrelevant to the comparison. The fact that all nodes have unique labels makes the problem quite tractable: we can enumerate non-empty subsets of the available labels because we know that the trees generated with one subset of the labels must all be distinct from the trees generated with a different subset. Since the subtrees themselves are unordered, we can canonicalise by keeping the subtree roots sorted (any ordering is as good as any other).

So we end up with the procedure `GenTrees(R, D, N)`,  where `R` is the root label, `D` is the set of descendant labels, and `N` is the maximum tree depth, which can be defined as follows:

- If `D` is empty, return a singleton set with the tree consisting only of the indicated root node.
- (For efficiency) If `N` is 1, return a singleton set with the tree consisting of the indicated root node with the remaining nodes as leaves. (The less efficient step is "If `N` is 0, return the empty set." But it's better to shortcut by checking for `N == 1`.)
- Otherwise, start with an empty set of possible trees, and
- For every non-empty subset `S` of `D` (these are the children of the root node):

  - For every ordered partition `P` of `D - S` into `|S|` subsets (these are the remaining descendants of each subtree):

    - Add to the return set all trees with root `R` whose children are in `GenTrees(Si, Pi, N-1)`. (This is a cartesian product. Here, the ordering of `S` is arbitrary but must be consistent; sorting the labels into ascending order would be an obvious solution.)

By way of testing the above a little, I wrote a sample implementation in Python. It makes no attempt to be efficient, and is basically a transcription of the above using python generators. (The advantage of generators is that we don't have to fill memory with the millions of possible trees; we just generate one at a time.)

In case it is clearer than the verbiage, here it is:

```
from functools import reduce
from itertools import product

class tree(object):
  def __init__(self, root, kids=()):
    self.root = root
    self.kids = tuple(kids)

  def __str__(self):
    '''Produce an S-expr for the tree.'''
    if self.kids:
      return "(%s %s)" % (self.root,
                          ' '.join(str(kid) for kid in self.kids))
    else:
      return self.root

def append(part, wherewhat):
  part[wherewhat[0]].append(wherewhat[1])
  return part

def gentrees(root, labels, N):
  if not labels or N <= 1:
    yield tree(root, labels if N else ())
  else:
    for p in product((0,1), repeat = len(labels)):
      if any(p):
        nexts, roots = reduce(append, zip(p, labels), ([], []))
        for q in product(range(len(roots)), repeat = len(nexts)):
          kidsets = reduce(append, zip(q, nexts), tuple([] for i in roots))
          yield from (tree(root, kids)
                      for kids in product(*(gentrees(root, rest, N-1)
                                            for root, rest in zip(roots, kidsets))))    

def alltrees(labels, N):
  for i, root in enumerate(labels):
    yield from gentrees(root, labels[:i] + labels[i+1:], N)
```

The last function iterates over all possible roots and calls gentrees with each one. Here's a sample output, for three nodes and maximum depth 2 (this function counts depth in links, not nodes):

```
>>> print('\n'.join(map(str,alltrees("ABC",2))))
(A (C B))
(A (B C))
(A B C)
(B (C A))
(B (A C))
(B A C)
(C (B A))
(C (A B))
(C A B)
```

Worth noting that the count of generated trees increases exponentially with the number of node labels. Unless you are limiting yourself to very small trees, you should probably make some attempt to prune the generation recursion whenever possible (top-down or bottom-up or both).

Comment: Thanks a lot for engaging with me. I think your answer seems to be the perfect one but I must implement it and get back to you with any queries. Also how do I represent these partitions and trees in python. Do I come up with a way to link S-expression to structure of tree?

Comment: @haskar: In Python, I'd use a set for a set and a list of sets for the partition. Actually constructing the trees will require some kind of Tree object (which, in the simplest implementation, would consist of a tuple of the root and a set of children trees)

Comment: @HaskarP: Quite right. Unless you find it more natural to use a different argument order; that's not an essential part of the algorithm. You might put N first, for example.

Comment: @HaskarP: Also, there are really a huge number of possible trees. So you'd make it much more practical if you can short-circuit generation in cases where you can detect that the top of the tree won't be selected afterwards.

Comment: What do you mean 'short-circuit generation in cases where you can detect that the top of the tree won't be selected afterwards' ? Not sure if I mentioned it before but after I generate all these trees , i would only select those ones where children nodes add up to parent node(with some tolerance) (since I am dealing with energy data). So , it would look like some sort of max-heap tree

Comment: Ok.  I guess instead of generating an entire tree , you can look at the partition and the root of that partition and ignore generating it if it does not obey max-heap property.

Comment: Additionally @rici , for my purpose , I need to consider the case where the top-level has multiple nodes. In the algorithm proposed , the toplevel node(i.e root) is R (i.e  a single root) . So, a natural extension , I would assume is to create another higher virtual layer/transformation similar to Johnson's Algorithm for APSP problem and then initiate the algorithm with this 'fake' node as the root. Does this approach make sense?

Comment: @haskar: yes on both counts.